# How to get selected value from the Tkinter OptionMenu

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu, tkinter.optionmenu

I am trying to get the selected option from the given below OptionMenu, but I am not able to use the selected value globally.

```
def callback(selection):
    print(selection)
    return selection 
yearl=Label(Frame1, text='Select Year ',font=("Helvetica", 10) ).place(relx=-0.3, rely=-1.40)
valueyear= ['2018', '2019', '2020','2021', '2022', '2023']
n =StringVar(Frame1) 
n.set(valueyear[0])
yearchoosen = OptionMenu(Frame1, n, *valueyear, command=callback).place(relx=0.3, rely=-1.45, 
width=160)
```

In callback function I am getting the correct selected value but, I  want to use selection value in other function as well.

Comment: Try `yearchoosen = OptionMenu(Frame1, n, *valueyear, command=callback,variable=n)` and inside the function say `n.get()` ? And also your Q remains unclear

Comment: Thanks for your quick response,
I am getting selected value in "selection" inside callback function, but i am not able to use the same value outside callback function.

Comment: Did you follow the steps I commented?

Comment: yes I tried and i am getting value using "n.get" now how to access the same value outside the callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the value outside the function or anywhere in the code and its all fine, because your defining it on the main block:

```
def callback(selection):
    print(n.get())
 
yearl = Label(Frame1, text='Select Year ',font=("Helvetica", 10) )
yearl.place(relx=-0.3, rely=-1.40)

valueyear = ['2018', '2019', '2020','2021', '2022', '2023']
n = StringVar(Frame1) 
n.set(valueyear[0])

yearchoosen = OptionMenu(Frame1, n, *valueyear, command=callback,variable=n)
yearchoosen.place(relx=0.3, rely=-1.45, width=160) #so yearchoosen wont return None
```

`n` and `n.get()` is accessible anywhere from your code.

To test this, just make a dummy function:

```
def dummy():
    print('This is the value from the option menu',n.get())

dummy_b = Button(Frame1, text='Dummy',command=dummy)
dummy_b.pack()
```

When clicked, this button will also return the value chosen from the `OptionMenu`.

Comment: can you please reach me "gulamhmd20@gmail.com" I need help.

Comment: @GulamAhmed You can specify your help here? Not really into gmail