# Using dictionary to make Option menu and receive the values on selection, with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am try to use a OptionMenu in my GUI, I am unable to get the value of selected item in OptionMenu.I am unable to write the function properly.

Following is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

variable = StringVar(root)
options = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}

O_menu = OptionMenu(root, variable, *options.keys()).pack()

def sample():
    #here i want to write a function so that when I select "one", the result should print 1.
    pass


bu = Button(root, text="print", command=sample).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Additionally I want OptionMenu with default value of `one` to be selected when I start the GUI.

Comment: Look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64521595/how-to-get-selected-value-from-the-tkinter-optionmenu).

Comment: FYI, you said `combobox` in your question but you are using an `optionmenu` which is different.

Comment: you have common mistake - `O_menu = OptionMenu().pack()` assigns `None`  to `variable` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` always give `None`. If you need to use `O_menu` in other palce then you should do it in two steps `O_menu = OptionMenu()` and later `O_menu.pack()`

Comment: how about `print( variable.get() )` ? It gives selected text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `variable` in `OptionMenu` then you can use

- `variable.get()` to get value selected in `OptionMenu`
- `variable.set("one")` to set value in `OptionMenu`

---

Minimal working code with other changes

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def sample():
    selected = variable.get()
    print(selected, options[selected])

# --- main ---

options = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}

root = tk.Tk()

variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.set("one")

o_menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *options.keys())
o_menu.pack()

bu = tk.Button(root, text="print", command=sample)
bu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: It should be no parameter variable = StringVar()?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I have `variable = tk.StringVar(root)`. First: I use preferred `import tkinter as tk` so I have to use `tk.` before `StringVar`. Second: I could skip `root` from `StringVar(root)` (like I could skip `root` also from `Button(root, ...)` and `OptionMenu(root, ...)`) and it would use `root` as default - but sometimes it can make problem when you will have other windows (`Toplevel`) - so I prefer to do it explicitly in all situations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

variable = StringVar(root)
options = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3}
variable.set("one")

O_menu = OptionMenu(root, variable, *options.keys()).pack()


def sample():
    result = variable.get()
    print(options[result])

bu = Button(root, text="print", command=sample).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It should be no parameter variable = StringVar()?